# How do I prevent a popup form from taking focus from the parent

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a small windows.form that I use to present information when the mouse is over a regions on a windows.Form, however it takes the focus from the parent window when it is set to visible. Is there w way of preventing this - it causes the main form to flicker as it toggles between in focus and out.

c#, .net 2.0, system.windows.forms

Comment: Why have a popup if you are not going to give it focus (and this it will not be immediately visible to the user)?

Comment: Have you set TabStop=false for the popup and all its controls?

Comment: Why do not use ToolTip for that scope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paste this into your popup form class, it prevents it from being activated when shown:

```
    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation {
        get { return true; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

ShowWindow(popupForm.Handle, 8);
```

See [ShowWindow Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx) for additional commands.