# How does the combo box drop down window not steal focus from the combo box?

Tags: c#, winforms

In WinForms, if you have a combo box and you have the drop down open, the drop down window does not steal focus from the control. So you can still type into the combo box with the window open.

How is this achieved and can it be duplicated?

Comment: I think the answer is in the name, it is a combination of a text box and popup all in one control, so the drop down list is *part of the textbox*, not sure where you would find the exact implementation of the `ComboBox` class... might be fairly difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a popup form from taking focus from the parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175567/how-do-i-prevent-a-popup-form-from-taking-focus-from-the-parent)